# Is there any way in Grafana to do manual data entry in an existing data source (InfluxDB)?

Tags: grafana

For an application I have to visualize some data which have to come from manual data which will be inputted by the user, live and in the existing dashboard. These data will then have to be saved in the existing data base (based on InfluxDB). It would be perfect if we have any table where user can easily input the data (just some integers).